# R bulk upload data to MYSQL database

Tags: mysql, r, bulkinsert, bulk-load, rmysql

there is the package: RMySQL

How can I bulk upload lots of data to mysql from R? I have a csv with around 1 million lines and 80 columns.

Would something like this work?

```
dbWriteTable(con, "test2", "~/data/test2.csv") ## table from a file
```

I fear this inserts line by line...

Comment: I'd also consider the command-line tool for mysql as an alternative.

Comment: There are also MySQL GUIs such as Sequel Pro (for Mac) and Heidi SQL (for windows) that should have a csv import option...

Comment: If your data is outside R, and you're sending it to a destination that's also outside R, you shouldn't get R involved. That will just slow things down and introduce a lot of intermediate steps that could go wrong. One thing you _can_ do in R is to load just the first few lines to inspect the headers and column types. That can be helpful to ensure you have the table structure right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are inserting many rows from the same client at the same time, You can use INSERT statements with multiple VALUES

```
INSERT INTO test2(col1, col2, col3, col4) 
VALUES 
('val1', 'val2', val3, val4),
('val1', 'val2', val3, val4),
('val1', 'val2', val3, val4)
```

Here an example on how to create your query. I am using `data.table`  here:

```
dat <- matrix(seq(4*3), 3, 4)
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(t(dat))
query <- paste('INSERT INTO test2(col1, col2, col3, col4)\nVALUES\n',
                gsub('c','',(DT[,paste(.SD,collapse='\n')])))

   cat(query)
INSERT INTO test2(col1, col2, col3, col4)
VALUES
 (1, 4, 7, 10)
(2, 5, 8, 11)
(3, 6, 9, 12)
```

then you can execute it using `dbGetQuery`:

```
  dbGetQuery(con, query)
```

Comment: thats an interesting approach as well! I will try it and compare speeds

Comment: This answer doesn't work if your data is in a data.frame b/c `t(myData)` doesn't make sense for data.frames in general.

Answer (score 6):

Since you have lots of data consider using `LOAD DATA`. It's the fastest method of importing data from a file according to mysql docs.

> [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)
>   The LOAD DATA INFILE statement reads rows from a text file into a table **at a very high speed**.
>
> [Speed of INSERT Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-speed.html)
>   When loading a table from a text file, use LOAD DATA INFILE. **This is
>   usually 20 times faster** than using INSERT statements. See Section
>   13.2.6, “LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax”.
>   ...
>   **INSERT is still much slower for loading data than LOAD DATA INFILE**, even when using the strategies just outlined.

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/your/file.csv' 
INTO TABLE contacts 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' -- or '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES; -- use IGNORE if you have a header line in your file
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to flush out @peterm's answer, here's a function that loads a data.frame into MySQL via the `LOAD DATA INFILE`:

```r
saveData <- function(data, # a data frame
                     tableName, # table name, possibly qualified (e.g. "my_db.customers")
                     ...) # arguments to DBI::dbConnect
                    {

    query  <-  sprintf("LOAD DATA INFILE '%s' 
INTO TABLE %s 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' -- or '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;" , TEMPFILE,tableName)

    # WRITE THE DATA TO A LOCAL FILE
    TEMPFILE  <-  tempfile(fileext='.csv')
    write.csv(data,TEMPFILE)
    on.exit(file.remove(TEMPFILE))

    # CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
    db <- dbConnect(MySQL(), ... )

    # SUBMIT THE UPDATE QUERY AND DISCONNECT
    dbGetQuery(db, query)
    dbDisconnect(db)
}
```